Next.js: Fetching Data with next-auth
I have integrated next-auth into my Next.js project to protect API calls to the route handler:
// /app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const session = await getServerSession();

    if(!session) {
        return new Response("Forbidden!", {status: 403});
    }

    [...]
    
    return Response.json({});
}

If I'm fetching the route with POST:
// /lib/getData.ts
import { headers } from "next/headers";
export default async function addData(data: FormData) {
    try {
        await fetch('api/data', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: headers(),
            body: ""
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    return null;
}

I get an error:
RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header

It seems that Content-Length / Content-Type is missing in the header(). How do I add these values?
